# Spring: How can I keep routes in sync with URLs on the page?

Tags: spring, templates, url, model-view-controller, routes

How can I keep links in my UI templates (e.g. Thymeleaf templates) in sync with the corresponding request mappings in my Spring application?

I've seen that e.g. the Play framework uses the @router-Object within its templates. How is it solved by Spring?

One example:

Spring Controller - simple

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/users/{username}")
  public String getUser(@PathParam String username) {
    // do some stuff....
    return "user";
  }
}
```

HTML-Page

```
<body>
  <a href="/users/1">User details</a>
</body>
```

Now I want to change "/users" to "/accounts". I'm pretty sure that I've got to update every html page by hand to update the link. Is there an easier solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no simple way to do this with built-in tools from Spring. However, I don't think that this would be too hard to build. You would need the following:

- A YAML file with all of your URL templates defined
- A `Properties` Spring bean that contains your URL mappings (read from the YAML file)
- All of your `@RequestMapping` annotations would have to be prop values; i.e. 
  `@GetMapping("${urls.users.byUsername}")`
- A custom tag that knows about the `Properties` bean and can create URLs from the templates that were defined in your YAML file.